# Как добавить данные в MySQL из PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

К базе вроде конектится - пишет **localhost via TCP/IP**, а вот инфу не добавляет, просто выводит строку "*Ошибка в запросе!*". Добавил строку в базу через интерфейс phpmyadmin (оказалось ошибка была в типе данных в базе). И начал ее выводить через код - ничего не выводилось и ошибка не появлялась. Попробовал через PDO, получилось вывести ту строчку (хоть и непонятно, что с кодировкой, т.к. русский текст выводился как *"???"*, но это ерунда, хотя если знаете, скажите в чем дело - вся база и таблица и столбцы в кодировке **utf8_general_ci**, в башне html прописал еще

```
<html lang="ru"> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />)
```

Но инфа все равно не вводится в базу.

Выводится ошибка: **SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: mode must be an integer in** (она только при добавлении , $dbh в конец INSERT`а)
Только, что опять изменил код, добавил try и catch. Появились новые ошибки.
Подскажите как же все такие залить инфу в БД!

---

Для удобства чтения добавляю скриншоты

[image: code]

[image: data_db]

[image: db]

[image: Error]

UPD: Добавил еще закрытие базы в конец кода на 47 строку `$dbh=null;}`.
Теперь пишет 1 ошибку.
[image: upd error]

UUPD: Вот еще код в текстовом виде:

```
<head>
<html lang="ru">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<?php include_once 'header.php';
require_once 'library/simple_html_dom.php';
require_once 'functions.php';


// try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=php_dns', 'gtx', '678352saqejgf2');
    // foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from habra_post') as $row) {
    //     print_r($row);}
    try{
        array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true);
      echo "Подключились УРА!!!\n";
    }catch (Exception $e){
      die("\nWTF!!! Ошибка подключения! =( ".$e->getMessage());
    }
$html = file_get_html('http://habrahabr.ru');
$element='empty';
$date_nextd=date('y-m-d h:i',strtotime('+1 day'));
$date1=date('y-m-d h:i');
foreach($html->find('div.post') as $p => $item){
  $title1 = implode(" ", $item->find('h2.post__title'));
  $text1 = implode(" ", $item->find('.html_format'));
  $url_a = implode(" ", $item->find('a.button'));
  $url_b = explode('"', $url_a);
  $html_in = file_get_html($url_b[3]);
  $full_text = implode(" ", $html_in->find('.html_format'));



  try {
  $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $dbh->beginTransaction();
  $dbh->exec("insert into habra_post (title, text_body, reg_date, full_text, next_date, link)
              values ($title1,$text1,$date1,$full_text,$date_nextd,$html_in)");

  $dbh->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {
  $dbh->rollBack();
  echo "\nТа ну епт, опять ошибка =((( " . $e->getMessage();
}
$dbh=null;}
```

---

Ответ для @Dmitriy Kondratiuk,

[image: answer-search]

---

***Спасибо @Dmitriy Kondratiuk, нашли ответ. Ответ в чате.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для 5-той версии РНР попробуйте так, к сожалению сейчас нет возможности протестировать код.

```html
<?php
include_once 'header.php';
require_once 'library/simple_html_dom.php';
require_once 'functions.php';    

/* подключаемся к базе данных*/

    $bd = mysqli_connect("localhost", "gtx", "678352saqejgf2", "php_dns");




/*запись данных в базу*/

$html = file_get_html('http://habrahabr.ru');
$element='empty';
$date_nextd=date('y-m-d h:i',strtotime('+1 day'));
$date1=date('y-m-d h:i');
foreach($html->find('div.post') as $p => $item){
  $title1 = implode(" ", $item->find('h2.post__title'));
  $text1 = implode(" ", $item->find('.html_format'));
  $url_a = implode(" ", $item->find('a.button'));
  $url_b = explode('"', $url_a);
  $html_in = file_get_html($url_b[3]);
  $full_text = implode(" ", $html_in->find('.html_format'));

$bd-> query("INSERT INTO php_dns SET title='$title1', text_body='$text1', reg_date='$date1', full_text='$full_text', next_date='$date_nextd', link='$html_in'");
    if($bd==true)
    {
        echo "Все прошло нормально";
    }
    else
    {
       echo mysqli_error();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Неа, все равно не пишет - на странице выводится строка Oll OK
Но записи в базе нету =(
P.S: почему pdo не используете?

Comment: по pdo не знаю дело привычки. Если пишет "Oll OK" то теоретически  данные должны были записаться в БД. Попробуйте переменным $title1, $text1, $date1, $full_text, $date_nextd, $html_in просто присвоить значения, например $title1="заголовок" и так для всех остальных. если записи не будет перейдем в чат и пошагово попробуем все с нуля сделать

Comment: Наконец-то, что-то записалось в базу через код! (хоть и с кодировкой неправильной - но везде стоит utf8).
Но переменные выводят статьи, они не могут быть пустыми.
Только, что еще раз проверил - все переменные выводят, то что было задумано - только html_in выводит огромный массив, если поставить url_b[3] то выводятся строчные линки.
Что делать что бы записать сайт в базу(?

Comment: Я больше с бек ендом работаю по етому "Что делать что бы записать сайт в базу(?" - сказать не могу. Просто интересно, а что именно записалось в БД?

Comment: Ничего вообще не записалось, будто он даже и не приконектился.
А если ты про проверку, то вот такое я скормил коду:
// $title1='Заголовок1';
// $text1='текст1';
// $date1='2016-05-28';
// $full_text='весь текст бла бла бла';
// $date_nextd='2016-05-29';
// $html_in='http://habrahabr.ru';
Разве бекенд не включает в себя работу с базами?!

Comment: Опечатка )) имел в виду фронт енд.
$bd = mysqli_connect("localhost", "gtx", "678352saqejgf2", "php_dns");
где gtx - имя пользователя БД;
678352saqejgf2 - пароль пользователя к БД;
php_dns - имя БД.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40425/discussion-between-dmitriy-kondratiuk-and-alpha).

Answer (score 0):

Если с типом переменных и форматом полей в БД все норм то по идее так:

```html
<?php
    /* подключаемся к базе данных*/

    $bd = mysql_connect("localhost", "gtx", "678352saqejgf2");
    mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8");
    mysql_select_db("gtx", $bd);


/*запись данных в базу*/

$html = file_get_html('http://habrahabr.ru');
$element='empty';
$date_nextd=date('y-m-d h:i',strtotime('+1 day'));
$date1=date('y-m-d h:i');
foreach($html->find('div.post') as $p => $item){
  $title1 = implode(" ", $item->find('h2.post__title'));
  $text1 = implode(" ", $item->find('.html_format'));
  $url_a = implode(" ", $item->find('a.button'));
  $url_b = explode('"', $url_a);
  $html_in = file_get_html($url_b[3]);
  $full_text = implode(" ", $html_in->find('.html_format'));


$q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO php_dns SET title='$title1', text_body='$text1', reg_date='$date1', full_text='$full_text', next_date='$date_nextd', link='$html_in'", $bd);
    if($q==true)
    {
        echo "Все прошло нормально";
    }
    else
    {
       echo mysql_error();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ответ в вопросе

Comment: Какую версию РНР вы используете?

Comment: version = 5.5.12

Comment: Добавил ответ для РНР 5-й версии.

Answer (score 0):

переменные `$title1,$text1,$date1,$full_text,$date_nextd,$html_in` заключите в кавычки (каждую отдельно)